# RUN exe file with a script on Windows 7 32bit

Tags: windows-7, scripting, vbscript, google-chrome, 32-bit

I want to run google chrome on windows 7 32bit with following target path

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --kiosk-printing"
```

When I enter this path to Target Path field in chrome.exe properties it says Target Box is Not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing the end quote differently:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk-printing
```